# Jquery 2 scripts aren't cooperating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 jquery scripts, but they aren't cooperating, and i dont know why.
My first script "scrolltop.js:

```
    $(function() {
    $("a").click(function(){
        alert("test");
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        var strip = target.slice(1);
        if(this.hash && strip=="wall_menu"){
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $("#wall_menu").offset().top
        }, 1200);
        return false;
        }
    }); });
```

It works fine... but stops while i add this script "changecolor.js":

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $changeBtn1 = $("#content_0 div.button1");
    var strNewString = $('body').html().replace(/\is/g,'<spon>is</spon>');
    $('body').html(strNewString);
    $(".button1").click(function(){
        $('spon').css("color", "red");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('spon').css("color", "");
        },3000);
    }); });
```

When i add both scripts, works only "changecolor.js", even alert "test" from first script doesnt work :(

This is my head from .html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="scripts/scrolltop.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="scripts/changecolor.js"></script>
```

My web browser console, does not say where the problem is.

Comment: What if you change the order of the two files does it work? This is probably because you're replacing the whole body (`$('body').html(strNewString);`) in `changecolor.js`, and therefore the events registered (click()) will no longer be bound to a DOM element.

Comment: Changing the order of two files does not help. You are right that ($('body').html(strNewString);) is the problem, when i put it inside "$(".button1").click(function(){", my first script works fine, until I click "button1". Do you know maybe, how can replace my second script? It must change color for all strings "is" in my body for 3 seconds

Comment: Going to update an answer for the problem. Regarding that, you should maybe use button1 as an id instead of a class ("#button1" instead of ".button1") and make a css class for the elements you want to change the color and add that class to those elements dynamically when you click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because you're replacing the whole body (`$('body').html(strNewString);`) in `changecolor.js`, and therefore the events registered (click()) will no longer be bound to a DOM element.

Comment: do you know how to replace this method?

Comment: I've commented the question with a possible approach for what you want to do :)